# Makefile, source in multiple directories, dependency problem

Tags: c++, makefile

I am experimenting with makefile...mainly when sources are in many directories

I have following situation...

project/src/ contains directory A, B, Main

Directory A contains A.h and A.cpp; B contains B.cpp and B.h; and Test contains test.cpp

A.cpp includes A.h; B.cpp includes B.h and Main.cpp includes A.h, B.h

project/lib contains libA.a libB.a

Makefile for A and B is fine...no problem with that...i am creating libs from objects and 
then copying them into lib directory

eg. makefile for directory A, and similar for B

```
  all:test
  test : A.cpp A.hh
    g++ -c A.cpp -o A
    ar cru libA.a A.o
    cp libA.a pathto/project/lib
```

I have makefile for Main directory as

```
all: test
test: test.o
  g++ -I.. -L../../lib test.o -o test -lA -lB
test.o : test.cpp
  g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
```

Everything works fine...only thing that I want to solve is that final executable 'test' 
depends on objects from libA and libB, so when A.h or A.cpp or B.h or B.cpp changes, it should be made again
So, I now changed my makefile as

```
test: test.o ../../libA.a ../../libB.a
  g++ -I.. -L../../lib test.o -o test -lA -lB
```

Now, problem is how I can modify this so that it will make test again only when its 
dependencies are newer than the 'test'.
There is no direct rule to make libA and libB, which Makefile requires and complains about; 
since I am copying these libs from directory A and B into directory project/lib.

So, I guess one solution would be to call make in respective directory A and B when anything is new than 'test' but how do I exactly do that ? Or, any other better solution is appreciated.

Thanks a lot :)

EDIT

Here what I did and it solved the problem

```
.PHONY : libA libB
```

../../libA.a : libA
libA :
  cd pathtoDirA; $(MAKE)

../../libB.a : libB
libB :
  cd pathtoDirB; $(MAKE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need to add a rule which knows how to make libA and libB, then add the dependency from test onto that rule. The rule can either call make in that directory (recursive make), or explicitly encode the rules for building the libs in your makefile. The first one is more traditional and is pretty simple to understand. It works with almost all situations you will encounter in the field, but there are some [potential issues](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) that can arise if you have more complex build setup (I would probably go with it anyway because it is simpler).

Comment: +1 for 'RMCH'. I like make, but I'm a bit backward like that, and I'm happy with an inclusive make model that uses a lot of include and a lot of common recipes do maintain common compiler settings and reduce duplication. It was a bit of a pain to set up, though, and I think that 90% of people would probably get on better with a more modern tool (scons, cmake, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`make -C dir` is your friend here. Do something like:

```
PROJECTS = A B C D

build:
    for dir in $(PROJECTS); do \
        $(MAKE) -C $$dir build; \
    done
```

And list your sub-projects in the order you want them to be built.

Comment: [Don't do that](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/). It is error prone and scales poorly.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```
 A/
  Makefile
  A.hpp
  A.cpp
 B/
  Makefile
  B.hpp
  B.cpp
 Makefile
 test.cpp
```

**file A/Makefile:**

```
 LIB = libA.so
 OBJS = A.o

 all: compile link

 compile: ${OBJS}

 link:
  g++ -shared -o ${LIB} ${OBJS}

 clean:
  rm -f ${OBJS}

 A.o:
  g++ -c A.cpp
```

**file B/Makefile:**

```
 LIB = libB.so
 OBJS = B.o

 all: compile link

 compile: ${OBJS}

 link:
  g++ -shared -o ${LIB} ${OBJS}

 clean:
  rm -f ${OBJS}

 B.o:
  g++ -c B.cpp
```

**file Makefile:**

```
DIRS = A B
 OUTPUT = test
 LD = -L. -LA -LB -lA -lB
 OBJS = test.o

 all: compile link

 compile: ${OBJS}
  for DIR in ${DIRS}; do \
   make -C $${DIR} compile; \
  done

 link:
  for DIR in ${DIRS}; do \
   make -C $${DIR} link; \
  done
  g++ -o ${OUTPUT} ${OBJS} ${LD}

 clean:
  for DIR in ${DIRS}; do \
   make -C $${DIR} clean; \
  done
  rm -f ${OBJS}
```

Then you can:

```
 make compile
 make link
```

Or just:

```
 make
```

Everything, also in the subdirectories, will be compiled and linked together

Comment: [Don't do that](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/). It is error prone and scales poorly.